# Permission denied @ unlink_internal, Rails 5 with CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I have `Ruby on Rails 5` with `CarrierWave` application. I have a model `Post` and a model 'Image'. Each post has only 1 video (it has column `video` in the table `posts`) and 0 or many images (table `images`). Model `Post`:

```
has_many :images

validates :video, presence: true
validates_associated :images

mount_uploader :video, VideoUploader
```

Model `Image`:

```
belongs_to :post
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
```

The video is required, but the images are not.

`ImageUploader`:

```
storage :file

def store_dir
  "posts/images"
end

def extension_whitelist
  %w(jpeg jpg)
end

def filename
  "#{secure_token}.jpg" if original_filename.present?
end

def remove_original_file(p)
  if self.version_name.nil?
    self.file.delete if self.file.exists?
  end
end
# GENERATE RANDOM NAME
def secure_token
  var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
  model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.uuid)
end
```

`VideoUploader`:

```
storage :file

def store_dir
  "../videos/#{model.id}" # Not in the public directory
end

def extension_whitelist
  %w(mp4)
end

def filename
  "#{secure_token}.mp4" if original_filename.present?
end

# GENERATE RANDOM NAME
def secure_token
  var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
  model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.uuid)
end
```

There is no method `remove_original_file` for VideoUploader.
This a part of the view for form upload:

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
.....
<%= f.fields_for :images do |i| %>
  <%= i.file_field :image, name: 'post[images_attributes][][image]' %>
  ......
  <%= i.file_field :image, name: 'post[images_attributes][][image]' %>
<% end %>
```

The input element for a video:

```
 <%=f.file_field :video, required: false, accept: '.mp4'%>
```

This `posts_controller.rb`:

```
def new
  @post= Performance.new
  @post.images.build
end

def create
  @post= Post.new(post_params)

  if @post.save 
    redirect_to action: :new
  else
    @post.images.build if @post.images.size == 0
    render :new
  end
end

private
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:language, :name, :video, :slug, 
                                        :images_attributes => [:image])
end
```

There is no problem if I upload a post with 1 image. Everything works fine. The files (an image and a video) are uploaded and all data is in the database. The problem is when I try to upload more than 1 image. I see this error:

> Permission denied @ unlink_internal - E:/project pah/public/uploads/tmp/1515418372-4328-0043-1599/video.mp4

I am using `Windows 10`. All the folders (public/*) are with all permissions (except special permissions) for all users.

The problem exists ONLY if I upload more than 1 image, but in some kind, it is related to the video.

After trying to upload and getting the error, I see that the temporary directory is created with the file (in this case `E:/project pah/public/uploads/tmp/1515418372-4328-0043-1599/video.mp4`) in it. Image temporary files exists, too and the files are in their directories (store_dir). In the database at the first time everything is inserted, but because of this error it rollback.

Answer (score 0):

```
def cache_dir
  "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
end
```

- in the uploaders fixed the problem.